# Every Vector Space is Regarded as a Vector Space Over a Given Field.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

My linear algebra textbook makes the following statements:

> A vector space is frequently discussed in the text without explicitly
>   mentioning its field of scalars. The reader is cautioned to
>   remember, however, that every vector space is regarded as a vector
>   space over a given field, which is denoted by F.

I understand what a field is (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Field.html), but I'm wondering what is meant by "over a given field"?

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could please clarify this concept.

Thank you.

Comment: The scalar multiplication of the vector space $V$ is a map $\mathbb{F} \times V \to V$ is what it means.

Comment: This means that the scalars in the scalar multiplication are elements of that field.

Comment: @StefanPerko I'm not familiar with a "map". Can you please elaborate using more elementary terms?

Comment: @Stefan4024 So $ab = c$, where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are elements in the field, $F$?

Comment: @StefanPerko function, mapping. If you don't know the definition you should definitely look at up since it is literally used everywhere in all of mathematics.

Comment: $b,c$ are elements of the vector space, while $a$ is an element of the field

Comment: At the risk of making a confusing statement:  Technically, a vector space is really a $4$-tuple $(F,V,+,\cdot)$ where $F$ is a field, $V$ is a set, and $+:V \times V \to V$ and $\cdot: F \times V \to V$ are functions such that certain properties (listed in the definition of a vector space) are satisfied.  The tuple $(F,V,+, \cdot)$ is often referred to also as $V$, even though this means that two distinct things now have the same name $V$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't see a *vector space* as just a set $V$ of vectors $v \in V$, but rather as a structure of:

- a set $V$ (whose elements we call *vectors*),
- together with a field $F$ (whose elements we call *scalars*),
- and two operations (called *addition* and *scalar multiplication*) that satisfy a number of axioms.

As you probably know, we do not only add vectors $(\vec a + \vec b)$, we also multiply vectors with scalars $(k\vec v)$ and these numbers $k$ have to come from somewhere. They are the elements of the **field $F$**.

When a field is not explicitly mentioned, it is often assumed that the vector space is taken over the field of the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$. But you can take other fields, such as the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ or the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$. When relevant, you should mention the field and if you omit it, it's important to still realize *it is there*.

Answer (score 3):

It simply means that prior to talking about a vector space, one has to fix the field this will be a vector space over; the axioms of a vector space explicitly refer to elements (scalars) that can be  chosen in some given field. Since the text does not want to restrict itself by selecting *one particular field* (like for instance the real numbers), it supposes a choice of field has been made, but does not say which choice; therefore the chosen field will be designated by the generic identifier$~F$, which could stand for any field (but only one at a time).

For a vague analogy, consider a text about finance. Since it is talking about money, it has to assume a currency is chosen, since monetary transactions require a currency to be expressed in. However, the book has no interest in stating just which currency is chosen, since by say fixing the currency to be £, it would falsely suggest that the general stuff it has to say is only valid in countries that use that currency. Therefore the text might adopt a generic symbol like $C$ to stand for a fixed but unspecified currency

Answer (score 1):

The field $\mathbb{F}$ is the collection of *scalars* associated with the vector field. The most common examples of vector spaces are over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, but for many theorems in linear algebra, the only important algebraic properties that the scalars must have are the properties of a field ($\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ have additional analytic properties).

You use this field in the definition of a vector space when you define *scalar multiplication*: a map $\mathbb{F} \times V \to V$ which sends $(\alpha,v)$ to the multiplication of $v$ by $\alpha$, written $\alpha v$. Consequently, if you choose a basis, then $V$ can be viewed (in the finite-dimensional case, at least) as column vectors with elements in $\mathbb{F}$, in the same way that an $n$-dimensional real vector space may be viewed as $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ when a basis has been chosen.

For a simple example of using a different field, we can take, say, $\mathbb{F}_{2}^{n}$, which would be all column vectors whose components are only $0$ or $1$.

For a more interesting example: $\mathbb{R}$ can be viewed as an infinite dimensional vector space over the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 0):

For tangible examples for why it's important, consider $\mathbb C$.  This can be viewed as a $1$ dimension vector space over itself, or we can view it as a two dimension vector space over $\mathbb R$, or as an infinite dimension vector space over $\mathbb Q$.  These are three perfectly fine fields, but just saying "Let $\mathbb C$ be a vector space" is ambiguous until we know the underlying field.